# Is ortolan, as food, distinct from other songbirds?

Tags: substitutions, meat

Whole roasted [ortolan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortolan_bunting#As_food) has been a French delicacy for centuries.  For purposes of cooking and eating, does the ortolan have any characteristics that distinguish it from other songbirds of the same size?  Or can other songbirds substitute for it in the dish?

Comment: I would have thought the gorging behaviour in the dark would make them quite distinct culinarily.

Comment: Not sure, but I hear you can get others for cheep.

Comment: Given that they are gorged on grain, I would expect them to be fatty and taste like the grain. How different this would be to another similar passerine bird, such as one of the seed eating finches prepared in a similar manner,  I don't know.